# Creating a variable of type from interface in golang

Tags: go, middleware, go-gin

I am trying to create validator/binder middleware in go using gin framework.

This is the model

```
type LoginForm struct{
    Email string `json:"email" form:"email" binding:"email,required"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Router

```
router.POST("/login",middlewares.Validator(LoginForm{}) ,controllers.Login)
```

Middleware

```
func Validator(v interface{}) gin.HandlerFunc{
    return func(c *gin.Context){
        a := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(v))
        err:=c.Bind(&a)
        if(err!=nil){
            respondWithError(401, "Login Error", c)
            return
        }
        c.Set("LoginForm",a)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

I am very new to golang. I understand the problem is with the binding to the wrong variable.
Is there any other way of solving this?

Comment: Pass in a factory rather than a model variable. `type ViewFactory func() interface{}`

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand. Can please you explain more or give a link to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarify my comment,

Instead of having the signature `func Validator(v interface{}) gin.HandlerFunc` for the MW, use `func Validator(f Viewfactory) gin.HandlerFunc`

Where `ViewFactory` if a function type such as `type ViewFactory func() interface{}`

the MW can be changed so

```
type ViewFactory func() interface{}

func Validator(f ViewFactory) gin.HandlerFunc{
    return func(c *gin.Context){
        a := f()
        err:=c.Bind(a) // I don t think you need to send by ref here, to check by yourself
        if(err!=nil){
            respondWithError(401, "Login Error", c)
            return
        }
        c.Set("LoginForm",a)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

You can write the router like this

```
type LoginForm struct{
    Email string `json:"email" form:"email" binding:"email,required"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password" binding:"required"`
}
func NewLoginForm() interface{} {
   return &LoginForm{}
}
router.POST("/login",middlewares.Validator(NewLoginForm) ,controllers.Login)
```

Going further, i think you may have to find out about this later, once you have an `interface{}` value, you can make it back a `LoginForm` like this `v := some.(*LoginForm)`.

Or like this for more security

```
if v, ok := some.(*LoginForm); ok {
 // v is a *LoginForm
}
```

See golang type assertions for more in depth information.

Comment: This works perfectly. I found one more way though, Changing 
a := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(v))
        err:=c.Bind(&a) 
to a := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(v)).Interface()
        err:=c.Bind(a)

Comment: I m afraid this works only for simple case like you presented earlier. I strongly suspect things will get way more complex if you encounter slices, maps, chans, or struct pointers.